# How to compile video4linux for ARM?

Tags: linux, compiling, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, arm

I would like to use a webcam using a Linux over ARM board. Through reading, I have discovered video4linux so I would like to compile it for ARM. My unique notes are:

```
git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
# (alternately to get only the latest revision without history)
git clone --depth=1 git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git
cd media_build 
./build
```

How would I do this?

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/p/lejos/ev3/ci/master/tree/sdcard/external/

Comment: Which board and which distro? Raspbian has V4L in its repos (I can't remember if it's installed by default)